# Doctrine2 large collections

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have been playing with doctrine2 + ZF setup for the last couple of days.

One of the things I still can't figure out is the large array collection assosicaitons. For example let's say we have an entity called Post and each post can have many comments.

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
*/
class Post
{
  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post")
   */
   protected $comments;
}
?>
```

Now this will load all comments if I do

```
$post->comments
```

But what if there are, say 10000 comments for this particular post? Then all will be loaded which is not good. And as far as I know slice/pagination will not be available until doctrine 2.1.

Can someone advice me how I can paginate comments? With DQL maybe? if DQL, where do you implement this?Do I create a getComments method in the Post entity and do the DQL there?

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using pagination from https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions, it works great, at least for me.

**Edit**: Not sure this will help you, but here's how I did my pagination

**Controller**

```
// Create the query
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('p')
   ->from('Identiti_Entities_Pengguna', 'p');

// Sorting
$qb->addOrderBy('p.' . $input->sort, $input->dir);

$q = $qb->getQuery();

// Pagination
$itemPerPage = 100;

$records = new Zend_Paginator(
                new DoctrineExtensions\Paginate\PaginationAdapter($q));

$records->setCurrentPageNumber($input->page)
        ->setItemCountPerPage($itemPerPage)
        ->setPageRange(10);

$this->view->records = $records;
```

**View**

```
<?
echo $this->paginationControl($this->records,
                              'Sliding',
                              'partials/pagination.phtml');
?>
```

**pagination.html**

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>
<ul id="pagination-digg">
    <li class="previous"><a href="#">Pages: <?=$this->pageCount?></a></li>
<!-- Previous page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
  <li class="previous"><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>">
    &lt; Previous
  </a></li>
<?php else: ?>
    <li class="previous-off">&lt; Previous</li>
<?php endif; ?>


<!-- Numbered page links -->
<?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
    <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $page)); ?>">
                <?php echo $page; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li class="active"><?php echo $page; ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!-- Next page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
    <li class="next">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next)); ?>">
            Next &gt;
        </a>
    </li>
<?php else: ?>
  <li class="next-off">Next &gt;</li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: There is also a extension called LargeCollections too beside the Paginate extension.

Comment: where would you use the pagination code then. In $post->getComments()? Can we use DQL in the entity? or maybe in a service? can you give a code example?

@orhan same issue, where would you use the LargeCollection extension?

Comment: LargeCollections did the trick for me!I added the following method to my `Post` entity.`public function getCommentsPagination($limit = 10, $offset = 0)
    {
        $lc = new \DoctrineExtensions\LargeCollections\LargeCollection();
        $result = $lc->getSliceQuery($this->getComments(), $limit, $offset)->getResult();
        return $result;
    }`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. I couldn't find how to format comments here.

Comment: But is it correct to add such dependency in an Entity which should be persistance layer free?

Comment: i tried use of this sample code, but how we use of partialLoop in this sample, it dose not print data for me. i use echo $this->partialLoop('index/table-row.phtml',$this->records); and create a table-row.phtml and in this file i <?php
        echo $this->id; ?> but it prints empty ,

Answer (score 1):

You may consider implementing `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface`.

See ZF docs for more details:

- [Zend Framework: Documentation: Advanced usage - Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.advanced.html)

Comment: I don't want to do this Zend way. I am trying to accomplish this DDD/Doctrine2 way :)

Comment: @boosis - Zend and DDD are not mutually exclusive, can you explain your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 2.2 now has a Paginator class. See this link for how to use it with Zend_Framework:
[Reply to How to use D2's Paginator with Zend_Paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635194/doctrine-2-and-zend-paginator/9334016#9334016)