# doctrine 2 and zend paginator

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-paginator

i want to use doctrine with zend_paginator

here some example query :

> $allArticleObj =
>   $this->_em->getRepository('Articles');
>           $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
>
> ```
>     $qb->add('select', 'a')
>             ->add('from', 'Articles a')
>             ->setFirstResult(0)
>             ->setMaxResults(5);
> ```

is there any example code to show we can write a zend_paginator adapter for doctrine 2 query builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upshot, of course, is that you have to implement the `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface`, which essentially means implementing the two methods:

`count()`

`getItems($offset, $perPage)`

Your adapter would accept the Doctrine query as a constructor argument.

In principle, the `getItems()` part is actually straightforward. Simply, add the `$offset` and `$perPage` restrictions to the query - as you are doing in your sample - and execute the query.

In practice, it's the `count()` business that tends to be tricky. I'd follow the example of `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect`, replacing the `Zend_Db` operations with their `Doctrine` analogues.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to implement **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface**. It is already implement by **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator**.

You can simply pass Doctrines' **Paginator** to **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator**, which you pass to **Zend_Paginator**. Then you call **Zend_Paginator::setItemCountPerPage($perPage)** and **Zend_Paginator::setCurrentPageNumber($current_page)**. Like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination as Paginator; // goes at top of file

SomeController::someAction() 
{
 $dql = "SELECT s, c FROM Square\Entity\StampItem s JOIN s.country c ".' ORDER BY '.  $orderBy . ' ' . $dir;
 
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
 $d2_paginator = new Paginator($query); \\
 
 $d2_paginator_iter = $d2_paginator->getIterator(); // returns \ArrayIterator object
 
 $adapter =  new \Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator($d2_paginator_iter);
  
 $zend_paginator = new \Zend_Paginator($adapter);          
                       
 $zend_paginator->setItemCountPerPage($perPage)
            ->setCurrentPageNumber($current_page);

 $this->view->paginator = $zend_paginator; //Then in your view, use it just like your currently use     
}
```

Then you use paginator in the view script just like you ordinarly do.

### Explanation:

**Zend_Paginator**'s constructor can take a **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface**, which **Zend_Paginator_Adpater_Iterator** implements.  Now, **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator**'s constructor takes an **\Iterator** interface. This **\Iterator** must also implement **\Countable** (as you can see by looking at **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator**'s constructor). Since **Paginator::getIterator()** method returns an **\ArrayIterator**, it by definition it fits the bill (since **\ArrayIterator** implements both **\Iterator** and **\Countable**).

See this port from Doctrine 1 to Docrine 2 of the code for "Zend Framework: A Beginner's Guide" from Doctrine 1 to Doctrine:  https://github.com/kkruecke/zf-beginners-doctrine2. It includes code for paginating with **Zend_Paginator** using **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator** with Doctrine 2' **Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator**.

Code is here (although it might not all work with latest DoctrineORM 2.2) but the example is valid: https://github.com/kkruecke/zf-beginners-doctrine2/tree/master/ch7

Comment: That implementation is not correct. Even though it sort of works, When you run $d2_paginator->getIterator() it retrieves ALL entities from the database, and then Zend paginator just filters it out. So if you have alot of records which need to be paginated, this approach will be very slow.

Comment: Agreed. This ends up being a 502 for me because the script takes too long. That's only for ~20K records too. Not scalable.

Answer (score 2):

I was very surprised how hard it was to find an adapter example that doesn't cause performance issues with large collections for Doctrine 2 and ZF1.

My soultion does use the [the `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator` from Doctrine 2.2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) just like @Kurt's answer; however the difference that this will return the doctrine paginator (Which is it's self an `\Iterator`) from `getItems` without the entire query results being hydrated.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as DoctrinePaginator;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

class DoctrinePaginatorAdapter implements \Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface
{
    protected $query;

    public function __construct(Query $query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return $this->createDoctrinePaginator($this->query)->count();
    }

    public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
    {
        $this->query->setFirstResult($offset)
                    ->setMaxResults($itemCountPerPage);

        return $this->createDoctrinePaginator($this->query);
    }

    protected function createDoctrinePaginator(Query $query, $isFetchJoinQuery = true)
    {
        return new DoctrinePaginator($query, $isFetchJoinQuery);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination as Paginator;
```

to

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as Paginator;
```