# Doctrine 2.2 + Zend Framework pagination speed optimization

Tags: php, performance, doctrine-orm

I'm struggling with Doctrine 2 performce when using `HYDRATE_OBJECT`. When I switch from `HYDRATE_ARRAY` to `HYDRATE_OBJECT`, it takes nearly 10 times longer! I've used [doctrine 2 and zend paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635194/doctrine-2-and-zend-paginator/9334016#9334016) as reference:

```
$query = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
    ->setParameter('x', 1);

// Pagination
$paginator = new Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query, false);
$iterator = $paginator->getIterator();
die(); // 160 ms
```

vs

```
$query = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT)
    ->setParameter('x', 1);

// Pagination
$paginator = new Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query, false);
$iterator = $paginator->getIterator();
die(); // 1.4s
```

What should I watch out for? How to reduce the processing time and still utilize `HYDRATE_OBJECT`? Is there a better way to accomplish pagination?

***Edit**: Using `->setFirstResult($itemsPerPage * $page - $itemPerPage)->setMaxResults($itemsPerPage);` significantly decrease loading time, but when using `$iterator`:

```
$adapter =  new \Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator($iterator);
$zend_paginator = new \Zend_Paginator($adapter);          
$zend_paginator->setItemCountPerPage($itemsPerPage)
    ->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

Zend only knows about `$itemsPerPage`, (`count($iterator) == $itemsPerPage`) and thus the pagination links always calculate 1 page only. How can I accomplish a proper pagination using Zend_Paginator, and only load `$itemsPerPage`entities?

Comment: Have you profiled your code? It's hard to answer this without knowing what kind of business logic you have in your models.

Comment: No business logic in entities except ->add() for ArrayCollection. Rest is plain setters and getters.

Comment: Isn't setMaxResults a Problem when using OneToMany joins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this now by creating a Zend pagination adapter wrapper for Doctrine pagination;

```
<?php
class PaginatorAdapter extends Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator implements
        Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface
{
    public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
    {
        $this->getQuery()->setFirstResult($offset)->setMaxResults($itemCountPerPage);
        return $this->getQuery()->getResult($this->getQuery()->getHydrationMode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Horribly slow execution, by only loading $itemsPerPageentities for pagination

Comment: No, I mean specifically what did your custom implementation of `Zend_Paginator` do more efficiently than just passing the Doctrine collection to `Zend_Paginate`

Comment: The getIterator() seems to populate every single entry (E.G 10000 rows). Alternatively the setMaxResults would make iterator count(), always return the maxresult integer (not the entire collection)

Comment: @JonSkarpeteig: How do you use that? Do you use getItems instead of using the adapter as an iterateable object? Dos this work with OneToMayn Joins as well?

Comment: I use it as a regular Zend Paginator in my view scripts. For more information you can have a look at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html